# How to delete an appointment on someone else outlook calendar and sending a cancellation notice in c#

Tags: c#, outlook, appointment

I'm building a scheduler interview management app, and when a new appointment is inserted in the scheduler, I set the new appointment both to the person who is sending it and to the person who is receiving it, the first part is that I'm sending the so called appointment to the receiver as a Vcard but I also want to add it as a calendar object but I couldn't find how with MSDN info.
This is the code I use to add the new appointment:

```
private void AddAppointment(Appointment NewAppointment, string MailTo)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application(); // creates new outlook app
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem oAppointment = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem)outlookApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem); // creates a new appointment
            oAppointment.Subject = NewAppointment.Subject; // set the subject
            oAppointment.Body = NewAppointment.Description; // set the body
            oAppointment.Location = NewAppointment.Location; // set the location
            oAppointment.Start = NewAppointment.Start; // Set the start date 
            oAppointment.End = NewAppointment.End; // End date 
            oAppointment.ReminderSet = true; // Set the reminder
            oAppointment.RequiredAttendees = MailTo;
            if (NewAppointment.HasReminder)
            {
                oAppointment.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart =  Convert.ToInt32(NewAppointment.Reminder.TimeBeforeStart.TotalMinutes);
                }
            else
                oAppointment.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 60;
            // reminder time
            oAppointment.Importance = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlImportance.olImportanceHigh; // appointment importance
            oAppointment.BusyStatus = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlBusyStatus.olBusy;
            oAppointment.Save();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem mailItem = oAppointment.ForwardAsVcal();
            mailItem.To = MailTo;
            mailItem.Send();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            CancellAppointment(oAppointment.GlobalAppointmentID);
        }
```

This is the code I use to cancel the appointment but it only cancels to me (Im using the outlook app on my PC) but I also need it to be cancelled to the other person as well:

```
 private void CancellAppointment(string AppointmentID)
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application OlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            NameSpace OlNamspace = OlApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            MAPIFolder AppointmentFolder = OlNamspace.GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);
            AppointmentFolder.Items.IncludeRecurrences = true;
            foreach (AppointmentItem app in AppointmentFolder.Items)
            {
                if (app.GlobalAppointmentID == AppointmentID)
                {
                    app.MeetingStatus = OlMeetingStatus.olMeetingCanceled;
                    app.ForceUpdateToAllAttendees = true;
                    app.Delete();
                }
            }
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Please post the answer if you found it. Thanks.

Comment: Please post the answer

Comment: unfortunately, I've never found a solution to this problem and ended up dropping the feature

Answer (score 0):

you should use `app.Send();` before `app.Delete();`